# Execute action (task) in a toolbar button joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, jtoolbar

i am trying to modify the com_phocamaps to add the "Copy marker" action. 
I have created the button modifying **function addToolbar** with this line `JToolBarHelper::customX( 'phocamapsmarker.copy', 'copy.png', 'copy_f2.png', 'Copy Marker' );` in the **com_phocamaps/views/phocamapsmarkers/view.html.php** but i don´t know where i have to set the action to execute de COPY task. 
When I click this new button, Joomla throws a 500 Error.

I want to implement a litle function to copy the marker and set **Publish = 0** to change the map.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to write that function in controller

go to administrator\components\com_phocamaps\controllers\phocamapsmarker.php

and write this function

```
function copy(){
    // your code here 
}
```

Comment: this is msg if i click on the new button
 Joomla!
500 - Ha ocurrido un error.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6 SQL=SELECT a.*,l.title AS language_title,uc.name AS editor,c.title AS map_title, c.id AS map_id FROM `ufx0g_phocamaps_marker` AS a LEFT JOIN `ufx0g_languages` AS l ON l.lang_code = a.language LEFT JOIN ufx0g_users AS uc ON uc.id=a.checked_out LEFT JOIN ufx0g_phocamaps_map AS c ON c.id = a.catid ORDER BY

Comment: have you added the code in the controller file specified above ?